# Java libgdx program not returning allocated Memory

Tags: java, memory-management, libgdx, heap-memory

I am running a program in java ( Eclipse ) with the libgdx library. 
Now I am at the point where I realized that when the program was running for about a minute
the FPS drops from solid 60 to bouncing from 10 to 40. Also the allocated Memory from the program is rising constantly. But the Heap size is seemingly not rising.

My question is now why the application is not returning the allocated memory to the OS ( windows ) and if there is a correlation between allocated memory and FrameRate.

Here is a link to a picture of an extract from the jconsole data:

http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=jj9z6u&s=5#.UtFp9bSFd7s

( Stack overflow prevents me from uploading pictures directly... )

Comment: From you pic: 25Mb of memory isn't what you'd call a lot memory usage. I'd be careful to conclude memory usage is the problem. Java usually does not return memory to the OS once it has taken it. Even if it doesn't use it anymore.

Comment: Yes but as you see this is just the heap... the allocated memory goes up to 1,5 GB.. and still rising...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably creating a lot of garbage for the garbage collector to collect.

Use the heap analysis tools in Eclipse or in the ADT to debug the issue.  See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html for ideas.

Comment: OP didn't tell about Android, and libgdx has pure desktop implementation.

Comment: But if the garbage collector would cause the FrameRate drop, shouldn't it just drop when the GC is activated? And in the GC log it just activates ca. all 30 sec ( that can also be seen in the drops of the heap memory I assume )